# Misplaced annotation of text Cartopy

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

Ran into an interesting problem with the behavior of the text annotation functions in cartopy following the documentation which I don't think should be doing this - believe its related to how the text method takes the transform and applies it, perhaps similar to the issue shown here for .annotate ([Why the annotate worked unexpected here in cartopy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416600/why-the-annotate-worked-unexpected-here-in-cartopy)). Basically no matter what is specified in terms of lat/lon and the transform it always plots at the center point of the plot. Code sample below:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects

def basic_map(proj):
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
  view = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection=proj)
  view.set_extent([-120, -73, 23, 50])
  view.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'))
  view.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN.with_scale('50m'),facecolor='white')
  view.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('50m'))
  view.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
  return fig, view

proj = ccrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_longitude=-97.0000,      central_latitude=38.0000)
fig, view = basic_map(prod)
view.text(-70,41, 'Northeast', color='black', fontsize=20, fontweight='bold',transform=proj,
      path_effects=[path_effects.withSimplePatchShadow(),path_effects.PathPatchEffect(edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.6,facecolor='black')])
```

Comment: It seems the linked question's answer tells you the solution already. Did you try it? In how far does it not work?

Comment: That solution does not work. However, thanks to a suggestion from a colleague worked out that by passing proj' as the 'transform' argument I was making a mistake. The input transform for lat-lon needs to be ccrs.PlateCarre() as otherwise it thinks its an AEA pass.

Comment: ...which is what the linked question is telling as well.